# Sharepoint CSOM UserProfilePropertiesForUser does not retrieve any properties

Tags: development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I am having this problem where I need to get some specific properties of a user profile using CSOM but I do not get any property.

This is the code I am working with:

```
UserProfilePropertiesForUser profilePropertiesForUser = new
                UserProfilePropertiesForUser(ctx, targetUser, proper.ToArray());
ctx.Load(profilePropertiesForUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
IEnumerable<string> profilePropertyValues = 
                peopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertiesFor(profilePropertiesForUser);
foreach (var propVal in profilePropertyValues)
{
```

when inside the `foreach`, I can see that no properties were found, Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
    const string serverUrl = "http://serverName/";  
const string targetUser = "domainName\\userName";  

// Connect to the client context.
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);

// Get the PeopleManager object.
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);

// Retrieve specific properties by using the GetUserProfilePropertiesFor method. 
// The returned collection contains only property values.
string[] profilePropertyNames = new string[] { "PreferredName", "Department", "Title" };
UserProfilePropertiesForUser profilePropertiesForUser = new UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
    clientContext, targetUser, profilePropertyNames);
IEnumerable<string> profilePropertyValues = peopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertiesFor(profilePropertiesForUser);

// Load the request and run it on the server.
clientContext.Load(profilePropertiesForUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Iterate through the property values.
foreach (var value in profilePropertyValues)
{
    Console.Write(value + "\n");
}
Console.ReadKey(false);
```

Comment: yes, this helped me see the problem, I was loading the properties before they were needed to be loaded, and so the values never came back, Thanks a lot..